# Pythonic Way of Reducing Factor Levels in Large Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, categories, bucket, levels

I am attempting to reduce the number of factor levels within a column in a pandas dataframe such that the total instances of any factor as a proportion of all column rows lower than a defined threshold (default set to 1%), will be bucketed into a new factor labeled 'Other'.  Below is the function I am using to accomplish this task:

```
def condenseMe(df, column_name, threshold = 0.01, newLabel = "Other"):

    valDict = dict(df[column_name].value_counts() / len(df[column_name]))
    toCondense = [v for v in valDict.keys() if valDict[v] < threshold]
    if 'Missing' in toCondense:
        toCondense.remove('Missing')
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: newLabel if x in toCondense else x)
```

The issue I am running into is I am working with a large dataset (~18 million rows) and am attempting to use this function on a column with more than 10,000 levels.  Because of this, executing this function on this column is taking a very long time to complete.  Is there a more pythonic way to reduce the number of factor levels that will execute faster?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `groupby`, `tranform`, and `count`:

```py
def condenseMe(df, col, threshold = 0.01, newLabel="Other"):
    # Create a new Series with the normalized value counts
    counts = df[[col]].groupby(col)[col].transform('count') / len(df)
    # Create a 1D mask based on threshold (ignoring "Missing")
    mask = (counts < threshold) & (df[col] != 'Missing')

    # Assign these masked values a new label
    df[col][mask] = newLabel
```